# How should support for alternate credential types in twisted.pb be implemented?

Tags: python, twisted, credentials, perspective, broker

My project has been trying to implement a credential checker using [scrypt](https://bitbucket.org/mhallin/py-scrypt/src). We've tried implementing our own credentials and checker objects, but we've had a lot of trouble getting pb to use them.

Pb seems hard-coded to use MD5 hashes over the wire, which absolutely won't work in our implementation; we don't have a way to get the correct password in plaintext on the server side, since we're using scrypt, so we need a way to transmit the password to be verified in plaintext instead. We've tried using twisted.cred.credentials.UsernamePassword with our credential checker, but it doesn't seem to make it to the server. (we still get _PortalAuthChallenger instead)

The ticket at http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/4398 seems to indicate that a PBServerFactory subclass is needed in order to support custom credential checkers in pb, but so far I have been completely unable to figure out what to override in order to make it use a different ICredentials implementation. Are there any examples (or even just documentation) of how to get pb to use a different credentials class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PB isn't exactly hard-coded to use MD5 hashes over the wire; that's just the authentication protocol as it's currently implemented.  You can do pretty much whatever you want by implementing your own authentication protocol - which, in PB, just means an object that you get to call some authentication methods on.

Make your own object that implements `IPBRoot`, and pass it to `PBServerFactory`.  This just means you need to implement a method called `rootObject` which returns the root object for a particular connection (and then declare that implementation with Zope Interface, of course).

Your `IPBRoot` implementation should wrap a `Portal`, similar to similar to `_PortalRoot` in Twisted's implementation.

Then, make a remote method on the object returned from `rootObject` suitable to your application; maybe something like `remote_loginPlaintext`.  In this method you can authenticate users however you want, then call `login` on your particular `Portal` with whatever credentials are derived from that interaction and make sense for your requirements (and whatever interface, although for hopefully obvious reasons, `IPerspective` is what I'd recommend).

The fact that the somewhat inflexible `_PortalRoot` (which only supports 2 credential types; `IAnonymous` and `IUsernamePassword`) is registered as the adapter for `Portal`, making it seem a bit more official than it really is.  Don't think of it is as the "official" PB/Cred integration mechanism, just the "default" one.

It would be great if you could contribute a more flexible authentication mechanism (perhaps a full SASL implementation?) for PB so that we could support other authentication types.  I hope that you'll consider doing that when your application's particular needs are met.

Comment: Looking at _PortalRoot and the examples, it looks like the IPBRoot implementation shouldn't actually be passed to PBServerFactory, but instead should be registered as the adapter for what's passed to PBServerFactory... is this correct?

Also, it looks like [PBClientFactory's _cbResponse](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/twisted/spread/pb.py#L1107) is coded to expect a challenge/challenger tuple, and the [default challenger](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/twisted/spread/pb.py#L1331) in pb uses MD5; wouldn't that need to be changed?

Comment: 1: `IFoo(x)` will always return `x` if `x` provides `IFoo`.  So there's no need to register an adapter, if you pass in a direct provider.  2: If you're doing something different server-side with authentication, then you have to do something different client-side as well; you'll need to implement your own thing which is like PBClientFactory.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link to the preliminary fix we came up with: http://paste.skewedaspect.com/show/20/

Note that this requires the custom credential to be Copyable, and allows the default MD5 key exchange behavior to be controlled by the keyword arg useMD5Challenge.

Note: in our implementation we're leaving the checking entirely to the Checker and having our Credential object contain nothing but username and password, so no actual code is being serialized.